# Dynamics 365 contact sync is removing business fax

Tags: outlook, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I have contacts in Outlook that have a Business fax number:

[image: screenshot of Outlook contact]

However, when that contact syncs to Dynamics 365, it drops the fax number:

[image: Dynamics 365 audit history entry]

Is there a way to sync this value, or a way to customize synced fields in general?

Comment: Is that a programming question? I'd suggest posting non-programming questions to the superuser.com web site instead.